# Looking for advice on making this BNF grammar suitable for LL(1) parsing (left factoring)

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, bnf

I am working on a parsing project that uses an adaption of this grammar for Perl's regular expressions http://www.cs.sfu.ca/~cameron/Teaching/384/99-3/regexp-plg.html. I have simplified this grammar for my own purposes, like so (note that, because "|" is a token, I am instead using a comma "," so seperate productions for a given nonterminal):

```
<RE>      := <union>, <simple>
<union>   := <RE> | <simple>
<simple>  := <concat>, <basic>
<concat>  := <simple><basic>
<basic>   := <zero>, <one>, <onezero>, <elem>
<zero>    := <elem>*
<one>     := <elem>+
<onezero> := <elem>?
<elem>    := <group>, <any>, <literal>, <class>
<group>   := (<RE>)
<class>   := [<items>]
<items>   := <item>, <item><items>
<item>    := <range>, <literal>
```

I want to write a LL(1) parser to handle this grammar, and for an LL(1) parser the productions for `<items>` have some ambiguity. To fix this, I could left-factor them by adding a new nonterminal `<X>`, like so:

```
<items>   :=  <item><X>
<X>       :=  <items>, epsilon
```

But what I'm wondering is, could I just flip around the order of the second production in `<items>`, like this:

```
<items>   := <item>, <items><item>
```

and avoid adding a new nonterminal? It doesn't look like it breaks anything, after all the whole point of this production is to allow any variable number of sequential `<item>` symbols, and we still get that if we reverse the order. Am I missing something, or does simply reversing the order achieve the same goal as left-factoring in this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are trying to fix is that

```
items → item
items → item items
```

is not left-factored; both productions start with `item`.

Your proposed fix

```
items → item
items → items item
```

doesn't really help (whatever starts `item` can still start either production of `items`), but more importantly, it is left-recursive, which is *verboten* for LL grammars.

In principle, the "new non-terminal" is the correct solution, but in a recursive descent parser, you would probably do something like this:

```
def items():
  list = [ item() ]
  while couldStart(item, lookahead):
    list.append(item())
  return list
```

Comment: aha, left recursion. I may need to dust off the red dragon book.... I forgot a lot of this stuff. Thanks for that.
Are you suggesting that, in a real implementation of recursive descent, this problem can be worked around without left-factoring the grammar?  I can't see the solution you're proposing with that snippet of python.

Comment: @ErikNyquist: Perhaps the pseudo-python code doesn't help much. The point is that a practical RD parser uses loops rather than recursion, and it is possible to implement `X+` as a loop: first recognize an `X`, and then repeat as long as the next token could start an `X`. In C, I would have written that as a `do ... while` loop; maybe that would have been clearer. `X*` can also be recognized with a loop; the only difference is that the test comes at the beginning instead of the end.

Comment: OK I got you. I will indeed be avoiding recursion so I will soon reach the point where I have to implement this, and I appreciate the advice. I have not been able to find any IRC rooms related to compiler design, or even smaller sub-areas (i.e. LL parsers, BNF grammars). Do you know of any good forums for discussing these things.... besides stackoverflow?

Comment: @ErikNyquist: Not any more, sorry. That doesn't mean they don't exist :)